# Springboot Handing off a task to a new thread inside a function

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a function(f1) and at some point it calls another function(f2). I don't expect a response from  f2, just calling it would be enough. But this f2 may take some time to execute. What I want is f1 to async-call f2 and carry on with the rest of it's(f1's) work. How can this be done in Springboot?

```
private void f1(){ //first function

    //some logic

     f2(); //calling second function

    //some more logic
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just invoke `f2` in a separate thread?

Comment: I could do something like this.
`new Thread(() -> {f2()}).start();`  
But are there any springboot ways of doing this?